# How can I connect all those wires together?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm trying to install a light fixture and I need to connect all those wires together, but they have different sizes and there are a lot of them.

I was thinking to do the following:

1. Cut it so they have the same size
2. Strip one by one
3. Try to put it all together and twist it

Is that the best approach?

**More info:**
This is a chandelier from china, I was not expecting that it would require so much work to put it together.

Those wires are coming from lamps(LED G5 220v), there are ~30bulbs and instructions are asking us to connect all the wires together, separate by color, there are red wires(like the picture below) and also blue wires. The problem is there are so many wires that's hard to connect them all together.

[image: Wires]

Comment: What do the instructions say?  Is it even UL/CSA/ETL listed as being safe and legal to use(if not, your insurance will not be happy)?  Seems to be too many wires to connect together anyway to be safe, unless there is a special(expensive) connector for it.

Comment: Some sort of DIY chandelier? Line voltage or low voltage? details will matter here - please [edit] to provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that many wires, you may be best off connecting them in groups, then connecting the groups together.

You could solder them in clumps, with one new wire coming from each clump.  Then solder the new wires together.  Make sure you put adequate insulation over the joins.  Heat shrink is much better than insulation tape.

Or lots of Wago terminals, or other terminal blocks, if you have the room.

Answer (score 5):

This is typical of the cheap stuff we're seeing from faraway countries. The fixture is not safety rated, and is required to be to be installed in our AC power systems.  If it had been, they would have had to provide a solution for the "many wires" problem.

It should be sent back, as they knew they were ripping you off when they sold it to you.

If you insist on keeping it, your best bet is to convert it to low-voltage so it is running 12 volts DC or 24 volts at the most, and switch out the bulbs to be low-voltage. Put a *listed* DC power supply up in the ceiling rose.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's a lot of work and a crummy design.

Strip the wires further back (exposing about twice as much of the conductor), twist them all together and solder. You'll need a high heat iron and lots of flux to get the solder to stick to all the wires thoroughly. Cap it with a large wire nut and wrap electrical tape top to bottom to prevent shorts.

An alternative to soldering would be a large crimp connector. Strip the conductors further back, shove them all in the crimp connector, and be prepared to bare down with all your might. Any loose wires could wriggle out, and worst case a bad connection could cause it to overheat. Recommend coating them with anti-oxidant compound (Noalox).

Another idea would be to fabricate a screw-down terminal block but it'd be very long and may not fit within the fixture.